# Jquery Change works in firefox but not in IE

Tags: jquery

the below function is not triggering in IE8, but works in Firefox.

```
$("#datepicker").change(function () {
            AddOrRemoveOptionsAvailable();
        });
```

What needs to be done?

Comment: If you change `AddOrRemoveOptionsAvailable()` to `alert(1);` and the alert works, then it's the problem of `AddOrRemoveOptionsAvailable()`.

Comment: did you try doing alert(); in your change function...?

Comment: @xdazz & Sudhir You don't want to use `alert` for debugging, *especially* not when focus can be an issue (the `change` event relates to focus). Or at all, really.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, you're right. But it's just for testing whether a callback is executed here :)

Comment: Can you post the code of your AddOrRemoveOptionsAvailable? I'm sure the problem is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link may help you.

http://norman.walsh.name/2009/03/24/jQueryIE

Paraphrasing Alex...
 "If you click on a radio button, IE seems to wait with firing the change event until you leave the button, which is consistent with the behavior on other input fields (like text)"

```
$(function () {
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $('input:radio').click(function () {
            this.blur();
            this.focus();
        });
    }
});
```